# Problem when plotting data from .csv and converting the Date column in date time format - Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I am importing a .csv file that contains 2 columns (date, permits). When plotting the dataframe, I am converting the 'date' column to be the index and to be formatted as Datetime, but as soon as i do the latest, problems start with the plot.

I have tried two ways without luck:
Option 1) Importing with column 0 (date) as the index, and then converting to datetime format
Option 2) Importing the whole dataframe, converting 'date' into datetime and then adding it as index of the dataframe but all of them have issues

***code option 1:***

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BP = pd.read_csv('/Users/josedelgado/PycharmProjects/Fundamentals/Building_Permits.csv',index_col=0)
BP.index = pd.to_datetime(BP.index)
BP = BP.iloc[:(12*50)] #chopping the data since before 1970, datetime turn 1969 into 2069
print(BP)
BP.plot()
plt.ylabel(' Permits')
plt.title('New Building Permits - last 50 years')
plt.show()
```

[results of code #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Wow.png)

***code option 2***

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BP = pd.read_csv('/Users/josedelgado/PycharmProjects/Fundamentals/Building_Permits.csv')
BP = BP.iloc[:(12*50)] #chopping the data since before 1970, datetime turn 1969 into 2069
BP['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(BP['Date'])
BP.set_index(BP['Date'], inplace = True)

plt.plot(BP['Permits'])
plt.ylabel(' Permits')
plt.title('New Building Permits - last 50 years')
plt.show()
```

[results on code #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oynfm.png)

if i don't convert the date values to date time format, then plot is correct:

[right date sampling with wrong xlabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZLp7.png)

the sampling of the data looks **correct** here